# SSIS cannot load script for execution when click on edit script and build

Tags: sql, ssis, ssms

For some reason my SSIS script task in control flow and SSIS script component in data flow not working. If I drop an empty script and click on start it executes. But if I click on edit script and write simple code like

```
int a=10;
```

and click on build build is succeeded but when I click on start fails the package execution.

I tried with SSDT with visual studio 2017 and SSIS with Visual Studio 2019
with cannot load the script message as below for script task.

[image: Error message]

**For script component in data flow task it throws the below error:-**

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly '15872 bytes loaded from Microsoft.SqlServer.TxScript, Version=15.100.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. Exception from HRESULT: 0xD0000003
> File name: '15872 bytes loaded from Microsoft.SqlServer.TxScript, Version=15.100.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0xD0000003): Exception from HRESULT: 0xD0000003
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoadImage(Byte[] rawAssembly, Byte[] rawSymbolStore, Evidence evidence, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean fIntrospection, Boolean fSkipIntegrityCheck, SecurityContextSource securityContextSource)
> at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(Byte[] rawAssembly)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.VSTAComponentScriptingEngine.GetScriptEntryPoint(String versionGuid)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.CreateUserScriptInstance()

Comment: Smells like you have something amiss in the installation - not something you would have controlled, just something went haywire as part of getting SSIS on the machine. Uninstall and reinstall might be the best course of action.

Comment: This page seems to indicate it's a problem that's popped up, then been resolved, every now and again.  Perhaps you're just on one of the "troublesome" versions ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/301059/vsta-2019-unable-to-build-script-tasl.html

Comment: For your information, if you use VS 2019 Version 16.9, you must downgrade to 16.8. Because on ver 16.9 script task not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in Visual studio that caused the error. Here is the latest fix posted by Microsoft on there website https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects&ssr=false#overview
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaqpn.png)